# Issue with disappearing of close button when an overlay full screen menu opens

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress plugin for full screen menu. I have done it on desktop perfectly, but on iPhone Safari and Chrome seems have a problem, that when I open the full screen menu and scroll down（after scroll bounce effect）, the close button disappear immediately so that the menu can not be closed.

The code is below, I only use HTML and CSS to implement the menu.

```css
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .icon-bars {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1999;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .icon-bar.bar-top {
    margin-top: 10px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .icon-bar.bar-middle {
    opacity: 1;
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .icon-bar.bar-bottom {
    margin-top: 20px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .menu-toggle:checked + .icon-bars .icon-bar {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .menu-toggle:checked + .icon-bars .bar-top {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .menu-toggle:checked + .icon-bars .bar-middle {
    opacity: 0;
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .menu-toggle:checked + .icon-bars .bar-bottom {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .menu-overlay {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-overlay {
    z-index: 1900;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .menu-overlay .menu-content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .content-type-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .content-type-menu a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .menu-overlay-title,
.aglaia-jewelry-wrapper .menu-overlay-email {

    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
   <div class="aglaia-jewelry-wrapper">
      <input type="checkbox" id="aglaia-menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle">
      <label class="icon-bars" for="aglaia-menu-toggle" id="aglaia-menu-toggle-icon">
        <span class="icon-bar bar-top"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar bar-middle"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar bar-bottom"></span>
      </label>
      
         <div class="menu-overlay">
        <div>
          
        <div class="menu-overlay-title">
              <?php echo $additional_settings['nav_title']; ?>
           </div>
            
           <div class="menu-overlay-items">
                 <?php echo $content_html; ?>
           </div>
         
           <div class="menu-overlay-email">
        <a href="mailto:<?php echo $additional_settings['contact_email']; ?>">
      <?php echo $additional_settings['contact_email']; ?>
        </a>
        </div>
              
     </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**What I tried:**

1. I use position:fixed; or overflow:hidden; on body tag to prevent body scrolling when open the menu, and it works great on desktop safari, but not working at all on mobile.
2. I use event.preventDefault() on body tag, see the code below:

```js
 var fixed = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

fixed.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

the preventDefault() is working, but all my links (except menu links) on the menu overlay are not clickable including button and a. In addition, my shop page AJAX effect was lost after add preventDefault().

3. I set the menu overlay background opacity: 0.5; and I scroll down the menu, I can see the background color is darken. It feels like Safari add a fixed layer between my menu items and the actual overlay layer.
4. I moved the closed button to the middle of the overlay, and it still not work.
5. I also tried to re-write it that I use jQuery and css together but still got same effect on iPhone.

I have attached screenshot below:

[the menu open with no scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3vhF.png)

[scroll down the menu and close button disappeared on right top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kix5W.png)

You can visit https://aglaia.tech/agltest/shop/ on you iPhone Safari to see the real effect.

Any help would be appreciated!

Regards
Alan

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on my iphone, server not found error came up. Anyways though - just looking at the element inspector on the desktop and maybe this finding will be helpful.... your menu toggle is separate from the .menu-overlay class. You have the .menu-overlay set to a higher z-index and it's 100% height/width. Perhaps that is why you are not getting a consistent display. The toggle could be getting hidden behind the menu?

Comment: Hi @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000, thanks for your reply. The icon-bar z-index is 1999 which is actually higher than the .overlay z-index 1900. I tried to change z-index but still not working...